# Why does ubuntu show as "linpus lite" when I am in the boot manager? Is this something to be concerned about?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

I am new to Linux and have decided to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my PC. Before that I have been using Windows, Windows 10 Home specifically. However I see that whenever I go to the boot manager or when I try to boot it by going to "Change advanced startup options" and click the "Restart now" button, in Windows and then it takes me to a menu.

Under that menu after clicking on "use a device", I see the options "Linpus lite" and "command Linpus lite". After clicking on "Linpus lite", I get booted to ubuntu.

Why does this show ubuntu as "Linpus lite" instead of ubuntu? Is this a problem? Although while installing ubuntu, I did verify its ISO image. Is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: This is because the UEFI/BIOS system is programmed like that. Any other operating system is labeled as 'Linpus lite', and we cannot do much to change that. Think of it as 'another operating system (than Windows)'.

Comment: Hmmm can't be entirely true. Linpus and Linpus Lite are Fedora systems and often installed on Chinese and Japanse subnotebooks. It has the best support for their character sets. Aspire One/Acer, Northtec Gecko and AIRIS KIRA Series have it but it wont be limited to these. Could be that the installer used has a mislabeled uefi.

Comment: I use an Acer PC, could it have to do with that? The way installed ubuntu after verifying the ISO image, was using Etcher, flashing the ISO file on the USB and then later on Windows 10, after going to the "Change advanced start up options" and clicking on the "Restart" button, in the menu it showed up as "linpus lite" even although I got successfully booted to ubuntu after clicking it.

Comment: Etcher is a cloning tool, and does not introduce anything at all (copies each byte from the iso file to the USB drive). I am rather sure that this is a feature of the UEFI/BIOS system of the computer (which runs *before* Ubuntu starts).

Comment: AFAICT the BIOS detects the file \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi and lists it as 'Linpus Lite'.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it looks weird it is normal. As for why it is happening @Akeo who is a Rufus developer gave a legit explanation and given his credentials I believe him:

"I am pretty confident that the explanation from @SSi above (in a comment) is correct, in that the laptop's UEFI firmware is designed to detect if a `\EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi` exists on the boot media, and if it does, will propose to boot it under a **hardcoded** `Linpus Lite` boot entry."

As for the theory that DVD / pen drive burner software (such as Rufus or Balena Etcher) would be the cause of this: "I can conclusively state that you can eliminate Rufus or Etcher as a possible cause of the issue, as neither of these software install "UEFI bootloaders" or have the ability to edit UEFI boot entries."

We'd need to sample other computer (Acer, Dell, HP, etc.) and BIOS brands (such as Phoenix, AMI, etc.) to see which manufacturer or BIOS brands are affected. Linpus is related to Acer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linpus_Linux#Nagware) but this could be BIOS manufacturer or other related.

Comment: Rufus dev here. I can conclusively state that you can eliminate Rufus or Etcher as a possible cause of the issue, as neither of these software install "UEFI bootloaders" or have the ability to edit UEFI boot entries. Instead, I am pretty confident that the explanation from @SSi above (in a comment) is correct, in that the laptop's UEFI firmware is designed to detect if a `\EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi` exists on the boot media, and if it does, will propose to boot it under a **hardcoded** `Linpus Lite` boot entry.

Comment: @Akeo Based on your respectful credentials and insights I'll modify my answer.