# Acer Swift 3 boot manager, no USB is detected

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, bootloader, acer

I've followed the instructions on Linux TV, but once i go to the boot manager, i cant find the usb, the only thing there is the Windows boot manager and linpus lite

Comment: You've mentioned no actual OS that is on-topic here, and how devices boot external media (*such as USB drives*) is brand/model/firmware specific.  I have hardware that requires me to hold a key down whilst it is off for external media to be booted; other hardware requires me to select an option from within the firmware menu, whilst many require only a key during the boot process to boot... ie. specific to device & OS being booted; neither of which you mentioned (*only mentioning off-topic OSes*)

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363886/why-does-ubuntu-show-as-linpus-lite-when-i-am-in-the-boot-manager-is-this-som